# Selenium 2.48: wait_for_css broken with newest version

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I created the following extension for the webdriver (Python):

```
def wait_for_css(self, css_selector, timeout=7):
    '''
    Waits for a element to become visible (or present)
    '''

    try:
        return WebDriverWait(self, timeout).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located( (By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector) )
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        raise TimeoutException(css_selector)
```

The code broke between 2.47.3 and 2.48.0 and I can't figure out why.
I'm using the FireFox driver. If I switch back to 2.47.3 it works fine again.

This is the outcome as reported by Django

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_changing_credentials (base.tests.test_base.BaseTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 329, in run testMethod()
File "/pipeline/source/django/base/tests/test_base.py", line 99, in   test_changing_credentials
driver.wait_for_css("h4#change-credentials-header").click()
File "/pipeline/source/django/libs/webdriver.py", line 45, in wait_for_css
raise TimeoutException(css_selector)
TimeoutException: Message: h4#change-credentials-header
```

The element it's looking for isn't there on the first try but it should appear within less then 1 sec. The timeout is on 7 so it should work.

Comment: broke? how? please elaborate

Comment: @e4c5: Added the error message reported

Comment: do you have an implicit wait?